# Adding a foreign key drop down menu to django form

Tags: django

I have a contact information model/form which I want to add a contacttype foreign key to that should be displayed in a drop down menu:

```
models.py

class ContactType(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[validators.validate_email])
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey(ContactType, default='General Enquiry')

forms.py

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # contact_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ContactType.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['contact_name', 'contact_email']
```

If I leave the contact_type variable where it is, I get the following error:

```
no such table: contact_contacttype
```

Here is my last migration:

```
dependencies = [
    ('contact', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='ContactType',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('contact_type', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='contact',
        name='contact_type',
        field=models.ForeignKey(default='General Enquiry', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='contact.ContactType'),
    ),
]
```

whereas if I move it into meta class (should I?) nothing renders into the template.

So my question is, is a foreign key the appropriate relationship? And if so, how should I add the ModelChoiceField to the ContactForm

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the form; have you actually created that table, by making and running migrations?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I added my most recent migration file to the question, thanks

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate`?